# select Distinct values and insert into table returning duplicates

Tags: sql, insert, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, duplicates

I have the tables `Data_Excel` having the the details of person: `P_name,P_address,P_city` and the table `Person` which has `ID,startdate,enddate`, I have to insert values in `Person_location` the following values `ID,address,city,country,startdate,enddate`, the problem is that i want to insert values in person_location which has `ID,StartDate` as primary key i TRIED THE FOLLOWING QUERY BUT THERE ARE SOME RESULTS AS FOLLOWS :

```
SELECT Distinct A.ID,A.name,A.startdate,A.enddate,de.source,de.P_address,de.P_city,de.P_country 
    from data_excel de, person A 
    where A.name = de.P_name 
    and ID > 6566;
```

Result:

```
 `7552  Adan George H.  30/12/1928  31/12/1928  Recueil Financier 1928  Avenue des Trois Couleurs 17    Woluwe-Saint-Pierre (Bruxelles) 
  7552  Adan George H.  30/12/1928  31/12/1928  Recueil Financier 1928  Avenue des Trois Couleurs 17    Woluwe-Saint-Pierre (Bruxelles) Belgie
```

Comment: Data_excel has multiple enteries for person name and address, Id comes from person table, i have to take id from person table compare name against the data_excel and get the location details and eventually insert the id and locations in the Person_location table

Comment: So which row do you want to use for the insert and how can that be described. Earliest one, most recent?

Answer (score 0):

Hello 'user408437' this query work for get Duplicate Row on Your Table

```
with cte as
(
    select *,rn= ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id order by id) from tablename 
)
select * from cte where rn>1
```

and if Your Replace > sign from = then he get Single Row of Every Duplicate Rows

I hope it is little Work to Your

Comment: i append this part at the end of my query?